# Android TextView not shown

Tags: android, expandablelistview, custom-adapter

I have debugged and everything goes fine; moreover, in Graphical Layout everything is fine. here you can see the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/news_img1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image"
        android:text="Pizza Rondon"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image"
        android:text="Ingredients: meat, potato, tomato, salad included too. " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="60 Lei"
        android:textColor="@color/dimmed_red"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the result as this view is an item from `ExpandableListView`:

[image]

I dont set any data to TextViews inside my customAdapter. What could cause the `TextView`s to dissapear? I can't even see any difference between price and others two which are not shown, which do not differ much in layout.

Comment: Did you try changing text color - maybe it is set to white??? The price is showing because  android:textColor="@color/dimmed_red"

Comment: Can you change the background color to black and see what happens?

Comment: @Wildroid set it as an answer. I did not set the color to others, this fixed my issues. seems stupid as the default text color is black, and should be as far as i dont change it any other place by myself. Thanks.

Comment: @FilipLuch I just did - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try changing text color - maybe it is set to white??? The price is showing because android:textColor="@color/dimmed_red"